# How do I prevent my GPS-tracking app from stopping?

Tags: gps, standby, sleep

I'm running a very simple open-source Android GPS tracker:

https://github.com/herverenault/Self-Hosted-GPS-Tracker

I have it set to post GPS coordinates from my phone to my server every 30 seconds.  The problem is: it sometimes works, and sometimes sleeps for 3 minutes, or 8 minutes, or sometimes seems like it is completely stopped.

**What might be causing this and is there anyway to prevent it from happening?**

This is not a "secret" app or malicious in anyway; the person running it knows they are running it.  I just don't want to make the user re-launch the app every 5 minutes, or even whenever they restart their device (which the code says it supports already).

Comment: I'm using this on several devices, but my primary phone is a Galaxy S5 running 6.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android OS intentionally tries to prevent applications like this from running to prevent battery drain. For Android 6 specifically, you need to know about the [doze and app standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) features. Doze prevents applications from running when the device is not in use. App standby defers network activity for seldom-used applications. Both of these are likely affecting your usage.

Running GPS (actual GPS, not just location services), is a huge power drain.

If you don't care about power, you can try:

1. Keep device on with your application in foreground.
2. Whitelist your application for doze and app standby (see above link).

Comment: I'm familiar with these, and I know GPS is one of (if not the) biggest drains on battery.  That said, I still want my tracker to be posting updates _anyway_.  Is there no way to force this "stay running" behavior in Android?